# Kafka adminClient throws TimeoutException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a health thread that checks the state of my Kafka cluster every 5 seconds from my worker application. Every now and then however, I get `TimeoutException`:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Aborted due to timeout.
at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
```

I have tools to externally monitor my cluster as well (`Cruise Control`, `Grafana`) and none of them points to any problems in the cluster. Also, my worker application is constantly consuming messages and none seem to fail.

Why do I occasionally gets this timeout? If the broker is not down, than I am thinking something in my configs is off. I set the timeout for 5 seconds which seems like more than enough.

My AdminClient configs:

```
 @Bean
public AdminClient adminClient() {
    return KafkaAdminClient.create(adminClientConfigs());
}

 public Map<String, Object> adminClientConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, serverAddress);
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 5000);
    return props;
}
```

How I check the cluster (I than run logic on the broker list):

```
@Autowired
private AdminClient adminClient;

 private void addCluster() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        adminClient.describeCluster().nodes().get().forEach(node -> brokers.add(node.host()));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 things:

1. The default request timeout is 30secs. By setting it to a smaller value you augment the risk of timeouts for a slow request. If one request out of 1000 (0.1%) takes more than 5 seconds, because you query it every few seconds, you'll see several failures every day.
2. To investigate why some calls take longer, you can do several things:

   - Check the Kafka client logs. `describeCluster()` may require to initiate a new connection to the cluster. In that case, the client will also have to send an `ApiVersionsRequest` and depending on your config, may establish a TLS connection and/or perform SASL authentication. If any of these happen, it should be clear in the client logs. (You may need to bump the log level a bit to see all these).
   - Check the broker request metrics. `describeCluster()` translate into a `MetadataRequest` sent to a broker. You can track the time requests take to be process. See the metrics described in the [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring), in your case, especially: `kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=*,request=Metadata`

Comment: @Stempler - how did you resolve this issue ?
I am also facing this issue tried timeouts at different levels but still getting timeoutexceptions